# U. 22.04.3 LTS cannot access anything but en1 from dropdown menu

Tags: keyboard-layout

I don't see this problem posted, only a vaguely-related problem about a year and a half ago. Running only Ubuntu on a Lenovo W530. For about the last week - before the most recent update, I am unable to switch between en1, en2, and en3 up in the right-hand corner of the home screen. I get the drop-down menu, but cannot change out of en1. When I am in en1 and click on en2, nothing happens. The Settings>Keyboard menu is set up the way I want it, with en1 first, and the other two second and third. I tried changing the order there, and weirdly, when I put en3 first, the upper right screen gives me en2. And once again, I can access the drop-down menu but not change anything. Frustrating.

Comment: Please check you've applied all security fixes & updates, as your details (22.04.3) imply you've not applied all for awhile. This [22.04.4 annoucement](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/) shows the ISO release date of 22.04.4, but installed systems upgraded a ~week before that date.  *Check what you're running; if you've not applied all upgrades please do so, if you have and your system still reports as 22.04.3 then you've got a non-standard system & maybe other problems that need addressing beyond just what you're aware of*

Comment: Thanks for comment, guiverc. A few days ago, there was a significant update - or at least there should have been. My computer froze in the middle of it, yet I am still running 22.04.3 LTS. But when I use, "sudo apt-full upgrade", I get Calculating upgrade...Done and "all packages up to date". You are not kidding that there are other issues. I'm knee-deep in them and need major help of the Linux variety.